# Value of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+1)^2-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've been looking at this for a while, and can't seem to get anywhere. I'm looking to find the sum of $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+1)^2-1}.$$ I know it's supposed to be $\frac34$, but I don't know how to get there.

Comment: Well $\sum_{x=1} \frac 1{(x+1)^2 - 1} = \sum_{x=2} \frac 1{x^2 - 1} = \sum_{x=1} \frac 1{x^2 - 1} - 1$.  Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

Write it as $$\sum _{ x=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ { \left( x+1 \right)  }^{ 2 }-1 }  } =\sum _{ x=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ \left( x+1-1 \right) \left( x+1+1 \right)  } =\sum _{ x=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ x\left( x+2 \right)  } =\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \sum _{ x=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \left( \frac { 1 }{ x } -\frac { 1 }{ x+2 }  \right)  }  }  } \\ $$ which is telescoping series.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** $$\frac{1}{(n+1)^2 - 1} = \frac{1}{(n+2)n} = \frac 12 \left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+2}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You have $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+1)^2-1}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2-1} \hspace{0.25in}(\textbf{why?})$$
Now you can use partial fraction decomposition on the right-hand side to reduce the series to a telescopic sum.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

We have that

$$\dfrac{1}{(n+1)^2-1}=\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{2n+4}.$$ So

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{1}{(k+1)^2-1}= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2k}-\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2k+4}=\frac 12+\frac 14-\frac{1}{2n+2}-\frac{1}{2n+4}.$$